# WebDriverWait until_not and invisibility too slow on Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a page where a loader "ajax-disable" which appears for around 5-6 seconds and if everything is ok it disappers. I have the following code:

```
try:
  WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".ajax-disable")))
  print("Finished")
except:
  print("ERROR")
```

I tried both `until_not` and `invisibility_of_element_located` but no difference. So my problem is that it is too slow after the loader `".ajax-disable"` disappears there is a wait of around 10 more seconds until it prints "Finished" any idea why and how to make it faster so right after the loader disappears to continue? Also changed the timeout from 5 to 100 seconds but still the same.

Comment: do you have a `driver.implicitly_wait(0)` after initialising your driver? This could work

Comment: Thanks, yeah I forgot about it.